# How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, c-preprocessor, os-detection

If there's some cross-platform C/C++ code that should be compiled on Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows, how can I detect them reliably during preprocessor process?

Answer (score 608, accepted):

There are predefined macros that are used by most compilers, you can find the list [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems). GCC compiler predefined macros can be found [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Predefined-Macros.html).
Here is an example for gcc:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
   //define something for Windows (32-bit and 64-bit, this part is common)
   #ifdef _WIN64
      //define something for Windows (64-bit only)
   #else
      //define something for Windows (32-bit only)
   #endif
#elif __APPLE__
    #include <TargetConditionals.h>
    #if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // iOS, tvOS, or watchOS Simulator
    #elif TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
         // Mac's Catalyst (ports iOS API into Mac, like UIKit).
    #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        // iOS, tvOS, or watchOS device
    #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
        // Other kinds of Apple platforms
    #else
    #   error "Unknown Apple platform"
    #endif
#elif __ANDROID__
    // Below __linux__ check should be enough to handle Android,
    // but something may be unique to Android.
#elif __linux__
    // linux
#elif __unix__ // all unices not caught above
    // Unix
#elif defined(_POSIX_VERSION)
    // POSIX
#else
#   error "Unknown compiler"
#endif
```

The defined macros depend on the compiler that you are going to use.

The `_WIN64` `#ifdef` can be nested into the `_WIN32` `#ifdef` because `_WIN32` is even defined when targeting the Windows x64 version. This prevents code duplication if some header includes are common to both
(also `WIN32` without underscore allows IDE to highlight the right partition of code).

Comment: The OP specifically asked about `Mac OS X` versus `iOS`

Comment: @Paul, "code should be compiled on Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows"

Comment: Note:  People are saying that "__unix" is a catch-all, but it does not appear to be defined for me on Mac OS 10.7.5 with gcc 4.2.1 (gcc provided by Apple with Xcode)

Comment: @jdknight yes `__linux__` is the supported macro on all linux distributions, `__linux` is not supported on all linux distributions, `__unix__` should also be used in place of `__unix` for the same reason, since all platforms that follow the unix guidelines support `__unix__`, and not `__unix`, here is a more in depth description http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system

Comment: For QNX, `__QNX__` can be added. More Ref: https://github.com/emrainey/Concerto/wiki/Predefined-Macros-for-Code  + https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/compiler-tools/cpwcc.html

Comment: Aren't Linux and Macintosh actually POSIX?

Answer (score 36):

As Jake points out, `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` is a subset of `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`.

Also, `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is a subset of `TARGET_OS_MAC`.

**So a better approach might be:**

```
#ifdef _WIN64
   //define something for Windows (64-bit)
#elif _WIN32
   //define something for Windows (32-bit)
#elif __APPLE__
    #include "TargetConditionals.h"
    #if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
        // define something for simulator
        // (although, checking for TARGET_OS_IPHONE should not be required).
    #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE && TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST
        // define something for Mac's Catalyst
    #elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
        // define something for iphone  
    #else
        #define TARGET_OS_OSX 1
        // define something for OSX
    #endif
#elif __linux
    // linux
#elif __unix // all unices not caught above
    // Unix
#elif __posix
    // POSIX
#endif
```

**Note** that above checks `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` macro because `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` macro got deprecated since iOS 14.

Comment: I would also add `__ANDROID__` above `__linux__` as it has its own specifics compared to Linux.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that any code specific to Windows, that is the same for both 32- and 64-bit, be duplicated in the `_WIN64` and `_WIN32` blocks?  It's going to skip the `_WIN32` one if it detects `_WIN64`, which may not be desirable.  Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/4qTShCq1) might work better.

Comment: My Linux only defines `__linux__`, `__gnu_linux__` and `linux`, but not `__linux`

Comment: What is `#define TARGET_OS_OSX 1`? Apple and OS X defines its own macros.

Answer (score 13):

5 Jan 2021: link update thanks to @Sadap's comment.

Kind of a corollary answer: the people on [this site](http://web.archive.org/web/20191012035921/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system) have taken the time to make tables of *macros defined for every OS/compiler pair*.

For example, you can see that `_WIN32` is NOT defined on Windows with Cygwin (POSIX), while it IS defined for compilation on Windows, Cygwin (non-POSIX), and MinGW with every available compiler (Clang, GNU, Intel, etc.).

Anyway, I found the tables quite informative and thought I'd share here.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @Lindydancer http://web.archive.org/web/20191012035921/http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/01/c_c_tip_how_use_compiler_predefined_macros_detect_operating_system