# Compiling Source on Mac OS X - Missing ether.h

Tags: linux, macos

I'm compiling some C source that includes ether.h, but this file isn't available in my install of Mac OS X.  This seems to be a common file included with the Linux OS.  Any ideas on how to get this on my local Mac OS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This seems to be a common file included with the Linux OS.

Incorrect. `<netinet/ether.h>` comes with glibc. OS X's (Darwin's) libc should have its own equivalent, perhaps `<netinet/if_ether.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be available here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcpdump/tcpdump-9/tcpdump/ether.h

Answer (score 1):

On OS X Yosemite, `#include <net/ethernet.h>` works for me. You should probably wrap the include using platform detection as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor).