# Preprocessor macro for OS X targets?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a project that has both an iOS and an OS X target. Is there a preprocessor macro that is true when I'm compiling for OS X? I tried this:

```
#if TARGET_OS_MAC
@interface BFNode : NSObject <NSPasteboardReading, NSPasteboardWriting> {
#else
@interface BFNode : NSObject {
#endif
```

But `TARGET_OS_MAC` doesn't seem to work. When I try to run the app on iOS I get a compiler error, because it tries to compile the first line and there is no `NSPasteboardReading` protocol defined on iOS.

I know there is `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` too. If I use that and swap the `@interface` declarations it works.

But there are a lot of places where I have code, that has no iOS version, so I need a macro for OS X too.

**SOLUTION:**

I ended up defining a new macro in the .pch file:

```
#define TARGET_OSX TARGET_OS_IPHONE == 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because `TARGET_OS_MAC` is defined when building for iOS as well.

See http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2010/8/16/TargetConditionalsh.html on that.

I would try and build my own target specific define via build-settings on the target.

Comment: also dont forget #include <TargetConditionals.h> // required in Xcode 8+

Answer (score 67):

The documentation in `TargetConditionals.h` has this diagram (it seems, as of 2022; any platform):

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                            TARGET_OS_MAC                            |
| +---+ +-----------------------------------------------+ +---------+ |
| |   | |               TARGET_OS_IPHONE                | |         | |
| |   | | +---------------+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ | |         | |
| |   | | |      IOS      | |    | |       | |        | | |         | |
| |OSX| | |+-------------+| | TV | | WATCH | | BRIDGE | | |DRIVERKIT| |
| |   | | || MACCATALYST || |    | |       | |        | | |         | |
| |   | | |+-------------+| |    | |       | |        | | |         | |
| |   | | +---------------+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ | |         | |
| +---+ +-----------------------------------------------+ +---------+ |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This tells us:

- `TARGET_OS_MAC` will be `1` for (probably) any Cocoa application running on an Apple platform.

  - `TARGET_OS_OSX` will only be `1` for macOS targets
  - `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` will be `1` for any non-Mac Apple products

    - `TARGET_OS_IOS` is just for iOS

      - `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` is just for [Project Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/). It seems `TARGET_OS_UIKITFORMAC` will also work.
    - `TARGET_OS_TV` is just for tvOS
    - `TARGET_OS_WATCH` is just for watchOS
    - `TARGET_OS_BRIDGE` is just for [bridgeOS](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/bridgeOS) (which currently doesn't even support 3rd-party apps so you'll likely always see that be `0`)
  - `TARGET_OS_DRIVERKIT` will be `1` when building for [DriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit)

---

#### ⚠️ But wait! ⚠️

I got that from the iOS 14 (macOS 11, watchOS 7) SDK. If I look back into the iOS 13 (macOS 10.15, watchOS 6) SDK, I see this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                TARGET_OS_MAC                                   |
| +---+  +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |   |  |          TARGET_OS_IPHONE                           | |
| |OSX|  | +-----+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ +-------------+ | |
| |   |  | | IOS | | TV | | WATCH | | BRIDGE | | MACCATALYST | | |
| |   |  | +-----+ +----+ +-------+ +--------+ +-------------+ | |
| +---+  +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Notably, `TARGET_OS_DRIVERKIT` is new in 14, and `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` is inside `IOS` now. This tells us that **compiling against the iOS 14 / macOS 11 SDK can break some C code written for iOS 13 / macOS 10.15**, if it assumes that `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` and `TARGET_OS_IOS` are completely separate.

---

#### There's More!

Additionally, these are defined:

- `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` is just for [iOS, tvOS, and watchOS simulators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html). You can further refine this using the above `#define`s
- `TARGET_OS_WIN32` is in case you wanna use Apple's SDKs to make Windows apps. I don't personally know of any other than Apple's own (like iTunes, Safari, and QuickTime). This might become useful now that Swift has Windows support, if you want to take existing Objective-C code with you.
- `TARGET_OS_UNIX` is for non-Apple UNIX systems

And these are deprecated, and should not be used anymore. That said, you might find them in code you have to maintain, so here's what they meant:

- `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR` used to mean the [iPhoneOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#iPhone_OS_1) simulator. Use `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` instead (along with `TARGET_OS_IOS` to target only iOS simulators)
- `TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED` used to mean iOS, tvOS, and watchOS non-simulated devices. Use the standard OS targets instead.
- `TARGET_OS_NANO` probably used to mean iPod Nano (I can't find any historical usage online). Apple advises to use `TARGET_OS_WATCH` instead.

---

Something else to note is that [the `TargetConditionals.h` which is used in swift-corelibs-foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/CoreFoundation/Base.subproj/SwiftRuntime/TargetConditionals.h) is significantly different, and includes `#define`s for Android, Cygwin, and other not-explicitly-supported-but-they-technically-work platforms.

I'm not entirely sure what to make of this. I would guess it's for compiling the Swift Foundation framework, and not for consuming it, since Swift doesn't consume `#define`s.

Comment: I remind you not to trust copyright infos in header files as reference dates. Apple Watch did not even exist in 2014.

Comment: `TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR` should also be mentioned perhaps.

Comment: @Pavel Good idea! I've added all those I thought notable 

Comment: Great!! But for C and/or C++ languages `#include <TargetConditionals.h>` is required (wrapped by `#ifdef __APPLE__` check), see [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920028/8740349) for more.

Comment: @Top-Master Since Obj-C is a strict superset of C, this will work for that as well. If you're compiling for macOS as this question asks, then you can use the `TargetConditionals.h` header (`MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/TargetConditionals.h`), which is just pure C macros. In fact it's so basic, I bet a C89 compiler would be fine handling it

Answer (score 15):

If you're using Swift, there's a great [language feature](http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/) for this. If you're using Objective-C, it's often useful to do something like this:

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>

#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
    @import UIKit;
#else
    @import AppKit;
#endif
```

Understanding the `TARGET_OS_*` defines will make this make a lot more sense. Most notably, `TARGET_OS_MAC` is any Apple platform which is pretty unexpected. `!TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is macOS and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is anything besides that. There are more specific defines for iOS, tvOS, and watchOS.

From `TargetConditions.h`:

```
TARGET_OS_* 
These conditionals specify in which Operating System the generated code will
run.  Indention is used to show which conditionals are evolutionary subclasses.  

The MAC/WIN32/UNIX conditionals are mutually exclusive.
The IOS/TV/WATCH conditionals are mutually exclusive.


    TARGET_OS_WIN32           - Generated code will run under 32-bit Windows
    TARGET_OS_UNIX            - Generated code will run under some Unix (not OSX) 
    TARGET_OS_MAC             - Generated code will run under Mac OS X variant
       TARGET_OS_IPHONE          - Generated code for firmware, devices, or simulator 
          TARGET_OS_IOS             - Generated code will run under iOS 
          TARGET_OS_TV              - Generated code will run under Apple TV OS
          TARGET_OS_WATCH           - Generated code will run under Apple Watch OS
       TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR      - Generated code will run under a simulator
       TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED       - Generated code for firmware

    TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR   - DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
    TARGET_OS_NANO            - DEPRECATED: Same as TARGET_OS_WATCH
```

Comment: Note about Swift: These days, it's probably better to use [`#if canImport(UIKit)`](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#ID539)

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 8 GM, this is the relevant section of **TargetConditionals.h** in iOS 10.0:

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC               1
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32             0
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX              0
#define TARGET_OS_OSX               0
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            1
#define TARGET_OS_IOS               1
#define TARGET_OS_WATCH             0
#define TARGET_OS_BRIDGE            0
#define TARGET_OS_TV                0
#define TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR         0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED          1 
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR     TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR /* deprecated */
#define TARGET_OS_NANO              TARGET_OS_WATCH /* deprecated */
```

(In the 'breadcrumb' above the text editor in Xcode, `iOS 10.0 > usr/include > TargetConditionals.h`)

...And this is the same file, for macOS:

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC               1
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32             0
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX              0
#define TARGET_OS_OSX               1
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            0
#define TARGET_OS_IOS               0
#define TARGET_OS_WATCH             0
#define TARGET_OS_BRIDGE            0
#define TARGET_OS_TV                0
#define TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR         0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED          0 
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR     TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR /* deprecated */
#define TARGET_OS_NANO              TARGET_OS_WATCH /* deprecated */
```

(In the 'breadcrumb' above the text editor in Xcode, `macOS 10.12 > usr/include > TargetConditionals.h`)

`TARGET_OS_MAC` is defined as **1** on both platforms, but `TARGET_OS_OSX` is **1** only on macOS.

In the file's comments, they are described as follows:

> - TARGET_OS_MAC: Generated code will run under Mac OS X variant.
> - TARGET_OS_OSX: Generated code will run under OS X devices.

I guess at some point back then (perhaps around when the iPhone was announced?) somebody decided that iOS (né "iPhone OS") fits the definitions of "Mac OS X variant".

Comment: I remember Steve Jobs mentioning on stage, back in 2007 when he announced the iPhone, that "It runs Mac OS X".

Answer (score 3):

Look in TargetConditionals.h for an entire list, including:

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC               1
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            1 
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR     1
```

Comment: You seem to have gotten it the wrong way around. Actually TARGET_OS_MAC is defined when building for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same situation, but needed it for Swift.

This answer here on the Apple developer forums was very helpful in dealing with the `NSPasteboard` protocols in your situation, but for Swift.

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16757

I ended up doing:

```
#if os(iOS) || os(watchOS)
  public protocol TFPasteboardReading { }
  public protocol TFPasteboardWriting { }
#elseif os(macOS)
  public typealias TFPasteboardReading=NSPasteboardReading
  public typealias TFPasteboardWriting=NSPasteboardWriting
#endif


@objc(TFCategory)
public class TFCategory: TFBaseModel, TFPasteboardReading, TFPasteboardWriting {

...

}
```

That way `TFPasteboardReading` and `TFPasteboardWriting` is defined for macOS meaning `NSPasteboardReading` and `NSPasteboardWriting` respectively and in iOS it has no meaning, but can still be referenced in iOS. So the code compiles properly for both.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this:

```
#define TARGET_OS_OSX (!(TARGET_OS_IOS || TARGET_OS_TV || TARGET_OS_WATCH))
```

Comment: it was not, at that time

Comment: But you answered in 2016... and I am looking at the `TargetConditionals.h` that appears to have been written in 2014? At least that's what the copyright date says: "`Copyright (c) 2000-2014 by Apple Inc.`".

Comment: Either way, it's bad practice to start naming things in someone else's namespace on purpose. That's how you get [#SmooshGate](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/smooshgate).

Comment: Yes, I answered in 2016 and I repeat it was not defined at that time. You should stop trusting copyright info in header files.

Comment: And this SmooshGate thing seems like a completely different story. This is not an implementation, just a preprocessor macro directive, which would cause compiler warnings if redefined. But if you want a similar case to SmooshGate, you should check non-prefixed category methods.

Comment: Sorry to spur any negative emotions. I'm only operating by the information I have; Apple doesn't to a good job of documenting what changes they make, when, and why. Also, the example I gave was in the spirt of demonstrating how trying to mimic an official API can lead to disaster when an official version is eventually implemented. This is why we never name our classes as prefixed with `NS`.