# Why is TARGET_OS_IPHONE not skipping over the code when building for Mac Catalyst?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, macos, mac-catalyst

I am using the Texture/AsyncDisplayKit library in an app for iOS and macOS Catalyst. It has this known issue on macOS:

https://github.com/TextureGroup/Texture/issues/1549

It basically throws the error `Use of undeclared identifier 'CAEAGLLayer'` when building for macOS Catalyst. Error comes from this block of code:

```
// CAEAGLLayer
if([[view.layer class] isSubclassOfClass:[CAEAGLLayer class]]){
_flags.canClearContentsOfLayer = NO;
}
```

If I comment this code out, then it builds successfully on macOS Catalyst.

So, I figured that I could use the `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` macro to exclude this code when building for Catalyst:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
      // CAEAGLLayer
      if([[view.layer class] isSubclassOfClass:[CAEAGLLayer class]]){
        _flags.canClearContentsOfLayer = NO;
      }
#endif
```

However, Xcode still continues to attempt to build this code and then fails.

Why is `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE` not excluding this code on macOS Catalyst?

**EDIT:** While I did find a workaround solution from this link:

https://github.com/nickaroot/Texture/commit/05a486e3275de53f2b0dfb24925fa528e2b610e6

by using `#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` instead of `#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE`, I still want to know why my original way doesn't work? The `!` (not) way seems weird.

Comment: FYI - Not directly related to your issue but `CAEAGLLayer` was deprecated back in iOS 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is annoying. The problem is that when you choose to build the macOS version of the app by selecting a Mac as the build target, then the definitions of `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` and `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` are both set to `1`. When you select an iOS device or iOS simulator as the build target, then `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` is set to `0` while `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is set to `1`.

I suspect Apple did it this way because a Mac Catalyst app is basically an iOS app, just built with a compatibility layer for macOS.

In my own iOS app that also supports Mac Catalyst, I use `#if TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` around code that is only for the macOS version, and I use `#if !TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` around code that is only for the iOS version.

You can see these definitions easily enough. Right-click on `TARGET_OS_MACCATALYST` and choose "Jump to Definition". You will be taken to the TargetConditionals.h file. Depending on your build target, you will be taken to different parts of that header file where several `TARGET_OS_XXX` macros are set to `0` or `1` based on the target. Try it for a Mac target then try it for an iOS target and you will see the appropriate definitions.

Comment: Does this mean that answers on questions such as below are incorrect when they say "...for macOS: #define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            0"
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442872/1634905

Comment: That answer is not saying to define `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` as `0`. That answer is pointing out than when you build a native macOS app (not using Mac Catalyst), that `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` will be defined as `0` for you in TargetConditionals.h. I didn't mention that case because your question was about Mac Catalyst, not a pure native macOS app.

Comment: Ah, I understand the issue now. Basically, the value is different for native macOS as compared to Catalyst macOS. Thanks.