# C Preprocessor Mac OS

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Should i use `__APPLE__ & __MACH__` or `__APPLE__` for my preprocessors?

I found about the `__APPLE__` here: [How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor)

and here http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems#MacOS about the `__APPLE__&__MACH__`

I'm not sure about what should i use.

Comment: Either way, it would be `&&`, not `&`. Boolean, not bitwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sourceforge documentation means that you can use either `__APPLE__` or `__MACH__`.

Answer (score 1):

Both macros are defined (on Mac OS X or iOS):

```
cc -E -dM - < /dev/null | egrep "APPLE|MACH"
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __MACH__ 1
```

To me that's fine to stick with `if defined(__MACH__) && defined(__APPLE__)` as pointed out by http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/predef/index.php?title=Operating_Systems#MacOS