# How to detect Apportable with preprocessor flags?

Tags: preprocessor, apportable

This is related to [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor)

When I build my project with Apportable, it assumes Linux/Android platform. I think these preprocessor flags are set.

```
__linux
ANDROID
```

But, my source code (OpenGL drawing) is not ready for Android, and only for iOS. So I want to detect some preprocessor flag for Apportable (not Linux or Android), and perform some iOS specific processing.

How can I detect Apportable platform in preprocessing stage? (What is pre-defined preprocessor flag for Apportable?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANDROID will be defined by the build system, however since the Apportable platform has numerous features that stock Android will not. `APPORTABLE` is defined to signify builds by the apportable build system.

You can find additional build flags specific for Apportable builds in

```
~/.apportable/SDK/site_scons/android/ndk.py
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily verify if a preprocessor macro is defined by using the message pragma:

```
// will always print, to detect cases where file wasn't actually built
#pragma message "-------------------------ALWAYS----------------------------"

// if the macros are defined, the pragma message should be logged
#ifdef __linux
#pragma message "__linux"
#endif
#ifdef ANDROID
#pragma message "ANDROID"
#endif
```

This will print out warning messages for macros that are defined:

```
/.../KTTypes.h:15:9: warning: -------------------------ALWAYS---------------------------- [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "-------------------------ALWAYS----------------------------"
        ^
/.../KTTypes.h:17:9: warning: __linux [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "__linux"
        ^
/.../KTTypes.h:20:9: warning: ANDROID [-W#pragma-messages]
#pragma message "ANDROID"
```

So yes, `ANDROID` and `__linux` are both defined when building with apportable, and not defined when building from within Xcode.