# Auto detect OS in C and handle with their specific line breaks

Tags: c, linux, windows, text-files, newline

Is there a way to detect the OS where the C code is compiled to handle with it's specific line break characters in text files? For example I compile my code on a Windows machine, it should use \r\n as line break in text files, on Linux it should just use \n.

I need this for a program which should read text files binary and match substrings of the file with other strings. This should work on windows and Linux.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Would [the use of macros help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor)?

Comment: If you're only reading files; just ignore (filter out) any `\r` and only use `\n` (this also allows you to read *nix files on Windows, and Windows files on *nix). You only need to care for writing files (but in that case, often you can auto-detect when reading and just do the same for writing).

Comment: I thought about using macros, but it's not very comfortable, because then I have to concatenate strings and can't use \n in a string...

Comment: thanks brendan, this could be the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know the native storage format. When *reading* a file, you cannot know if it was created on a Window, Linux, or other system -- it could be created on another system than the one you are working on. When *writing*, your program will use the native libraries for your OS and output whatever it deems appropriate for `\n`.

Reading a text file line-ending agnostically comes down to this:

1. use a binary mode rather than "text mode" (you seem to already do this).
2. read text until you encounter either an `\r` or `\n`.
3. if you get an `\r`, skip all next `\n`;
4. if you get an `\n`, skip all next `\r`.

This will work for line endings of `\n` (Linux and other Unix-like OSes such as Mac OS X), Windows-like `\r\n` and older Mac OS files ending with `\r` only. That covers about 99.99% of all "normal" text files you are likely to encounter. There used to be a very rare one that used `\r\n\n` (or possibly `\n\r\r`) but even that will be handled correctly.

Comment: Thanks! This will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to check for a predefined macro and #ifdef on it.
You can print all the predefined MACROs using the command

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

and grep for "LINUX" or "WIN32"

I'd expect to find _ *LINUX* _ defined on Linux machines and _ *WIN32* _ defined on windows machine.