# What are best practices for simple random shuffling in code that's both C++03 and C++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++14

Background: I'm shuffling the elements of a vector for a simple game. It should be possible to play the same game over again by passing the same integer seed — and vice versa, different seeds should produce different games. Cryptographic security (or any rigor at all) is not a design goal; cleanliness of code *is* a design goal.

C++98/C++03 introduced `std::random_shuffle`, which is used like this:

```
int seed = ...;
std::srand(seed);  // caveat, see below

std::vector<int> deck = ...;
std::random_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end());
```

However, as of C++14, `random_shuffle` has been deprecated (source: [N3924](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3924.pdf)). The C++14 way of shuffling a deck is

```
int seed = ...;

std::vector<int> deck = ...;
std::shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end(), std::mt19937(seed));
```

Here are the things that detract from each approach:

- The `srand`/`random_shuffle` way is deprecated in C++14, so we shouldn't use it.
- On some implementations, `random_shuffle` appears not to take its seed from `srand`, i.e., seeding with a different value doesn't produce different output! (libstdc++ on Linux doesn't have this issue, but Xcode on OSX 10.9.5 does.)
- The `shuffle`/`mt19937` way isn't part of C++03, so we can't use it.
- The `shuffle`/`mt19937` way appears to require that we pass the seed all the way down into the deck-shuffling code. For my application, I'd prefer to just "set it and forget it" via a mechanism such as `srand` that hides the global variable, rather than have to define my own global PRNG of type `mt19937`.  In other words: I don't want to be bothered with PRNG details, I just want to shuffle my vector!
- I *am* mildly worried about thread-safety (being able to simultaneously shuffle two different decks from different threads), but obviously not about thread-safety and "seedableness" at the same time. Consider thread-safety a "nice-to-have".

The first candidate I've thought of is:

- bite the bullet and pass `int seed` all the way down into the deck-shuffling code (avoiding global variables)
- use something like `#if __cplusplus >= 20110000` to use `random_shuffle` pre-C++11 and `shuffle` post-C++11
- to work around the `srand` "bug" on OSX, use the three-argument version of `random_shuffle` with some complicated functor... this sounds ugly

The second candidate is:

- screw C++03; just drop support for any implementation that doesn't provide `std::shuffle` and `std::mt19937` out of the box

But is there some *nice* way to solve this problem? I know it's a problem that nobody has unless their program is a toy program; but there must be *hundreds* of toy programs out there that have hit this problem!

Comment: supporting current and previous standard is enough, just drop c++03, it's antiquated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even in C++11, distributions are not standardized in implementation.

Write your own shuffler (for each element, swap it with another random elememt) and random number generator/distribution.  Weak, slow random number generators are short and simple.

I would pass your 'random factory' on down, and habe a method to 'fork' on thread spawning, as doing so also lets you do multiple 'runs' in the same execution.  Having explicit state instead of global is usually worthwhile.  But not needed if single threaded: just stuff the random factory into some global state and hold your nose.

There is no random shuffle that will bridge C++03 to C++17, so embrace a short hand written one.  It also ensures the same behaviour on multiple platforms, which is useful for a number of reasons (test coverage (same on different platforms), cross platform testing (bug on OS/X can be debugged on Windows), portability of myriads of stuff (save game files, io-based network gameplay, etc)).

Comment: "There is no random shuffle that will bridge C++03 to C++17": dang, that's what I was afraid of. You make good points that perhaps a hand-written implementation (with guaranteed same behavior everywhere) would be preferable to the standard `rand` (with behavior that varies among platforms). I might well go that route.

Answer (score 3):

First, develop a desired interface. 
It should hide from user any platform/compiler specifics, but give you all necessary data for implementation.
Write an unit test with a desired usage. Something like this:

```
int seed = ...;
std::vector<int> deck = ...;
my_shuffle(deck.begin(), deck.end(), seed);
```

Then implement

```
template< typename IteratorType >
void my_shuffle( IteratorType first, IteratorType last, 
                                       int seed = some_default_seed_maybe )
{
     #ifdef MACOS_FOUND
         // Mac solution
     #elif __cplusplus >= 201103L
         // C++11 solution
     #else
         // fallback
}
```

Does it look clean enough?

Check also: [How to detect reliably Mac OS X, iOS, Linux, Windows in C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor)

Comment: Well, so far you just repeated my "first candidate" from the question, replacing my English handwaving with equivalent pseudocode handwaving. (Except that you also replaced my FUDdy "some complicated functor... this sounds ugly" with the even-less-useful comment "// Mac solution".) If you flesh this out with actual code, it'll be interesting; but *simply* paraphrasing the question isn't the same thing as answering it.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::random::mt19937` as a fallback? I do this for threads with little worry.

Comment: @self nowhere, but it's a valid suggestion.

Comment: This is probably a reasonable answer for some use-cases, but I don't want my particular toy program to require Boost as a dependency. Sorry, no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I might be tempted to do something like this. It solves the "passing down the seed" problem by wrapping it up in a custom class. In order to make that less work I have privately inherited from `std::vector<int>` and just implemented those functions I actually need for a `deck`.

Private inheritance gives me some protection by making sure I can not assign a `deck*` to its base pointer (and thus avoid non-virtual destructor problems).

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L

class deck
: private std::vector<int>
{
    int seed = 0;

public:
    deck(int seed = 0): seed(seed) {}

    // access relevant functions
    using std::vector<int>::size;
    using std::vector<int>::begin;
    using std::vector<int>::end;
    using std::vector<int>::push_back;
    using std::vector<int>::operator=;
    using std::vector<int>::operator[];

    void shuffle()
    {
        std::shuffle(begin(), end(), std::mt19937(seed));
    }

};

#else

class deck
: private std::vector<int>
{
    typedef std::vector<int> vector;
    typedef vector::iterator iterator;

    int seed = 0;

public:
    deck(int seed = 0): seed(seed) {}

    // implement relevant functions
    iterator begin() { return vector::begin(); }
    iterator end() { return vector::end(); }
    void push_back(int i) { vector::push_back(i); }
    int& operator[](vector::size_type i) { return (*this)[i]; }

    void shuffle()
    {
        std::srand(seed);
        std::random_shuffle(begin(), end());
    }

};

#endif

int main()
{
    deck d(5);

    d = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    d.shuffle();

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < d.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << d[i] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Nice code, but I don't think this focuses enough on the `shuffle` issues to count as an answer.

Two nitpicks: (1) This doesn't address the issue of `srand` and `random_shuffle` not interacting on OSX. (2) In general, [inheriting from `vector<int>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353203/thou-shalt-not-inherit-from-stdvector) is bad, because of [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) among other issues; and in this case inheritance doesn't even save you any lines of code over composition, so I think you should just use composition.