# Fix a segmentation fault in connect four game

Tags: c

I work on a connect four game in c i compiled my code but i still have these 2 problems first this line on my terminal **sh: cls: command not found** i search on forum (may be an segmentation fault)but i don' know what to do to fix it enter code here and second when i compile the row don't appear on the screen can you help me please ?Thank you in advance :)

This is it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void display();
bool check(int a, int b);

int drop(int b, char player);
char place[6][7];//available for the entire code

    void display(){ //empty 

    printf(" 1   2   3   4   5   6   7\n");                     


    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
    printf ("+");
    for (j=0; j<7; j++)
        printf("---+");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("|");
    for (j=0; j<7; j++)
        printf("   |");
    printf ("\n");
  }

printf ("+");
for (j=0; j<7; j++)
    printf("---+");
printf ("\n");
}

int drop(int b, char player){
        if(b >=0 && b<= 6){
            if(place[0][b] == ' '){
            int i;
            for(i = 0;place[i][b] == ' ';i++)
                if(i == 5){place[i][b] = player;
            return i;}
            i--;
            place[i][b] =player;
            return i;
            }else{
            return -1;
            }
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
    bool check(int a, int b){
    int vertical = 1;//(|)
    int horizontal = 1;//(-)
    int diagonal1 = 1;//(\)
    int diagonal2 = 1;//(/)
    char player = place[a][b];
    int i;//vertical
    int ii;//horizontal
    //check for vertical(|)
    for(i = a +1;place[i][b] == player && i <= 5;i++,vertical++);//Check down
    for(i = a -1;place[i][b] == player && i >= 0;i--,vertical++);//Check up
    if(vertical >= 4)return true;
    //check for horizontal(-)
    for(ii = b -1;place[a][ii] == player && ii >= 0;ii--,horizontal++);//Check left
    for(ii = b +1;place[a][ii] == player && ii <= 6;ii++,horizontal++);//Check right
    if(horizontal >= 4) return true;
    //check for diagonal 1 (\)
    for(i = a -1, ii= b -1;place[i][ii] == player && i>=0 && ii >=0; diagonal1 ++, i --, ii --);//up and left
    for(i = a +1, ii = b+1;place[i][ii] == player && i<=5 && ii <=6;diagonal1 ++, i ++, ii ++);//down and right
    if(diagonal1 >= 4) return true;
    //check for diagonal 2(/)
    for(i = a -1, ii= b +1;place[i][ii] == player && i>=0 && ii <= 6; diagonal2 ++, i --, ii ++);//up and right
    for(i = a +1, ii= b -1;place[i][ii] == player && i<=5 && ii >=0; diagonal2 ++, i ++, ii --);//up and left
    if(diagonal2 >= 4) return true;
    return false;
}
 int main(){
    for(int a =0;a <= 5; a++){      //fill place with whitespace
        for(int b = 0; b<=6; b++)   //
            place[a][b] = ' ';      //
    }                               //
    display();//Displays for first time so players can see the board
    //declarations
    int hold;//Will house user row choice
    int hold2 = 0;//will hold drop value
    int charsPlaced = 0;//Number of peices dropped so can end game if a draw
    bool gamewon = false;//Will be changed to true when game is won and will exit while loop
    char player = 15;//start as player 2 will change back 2 player 1

    while(!gamewon){//will stop when game is won, ! means NOT makes the oppisite be checked
        if(hold2 != -1){//check if there was a error in the last drop
            if(player == 15){//if player 2 lasted dropped a piece so its player 1s turn
                printf("player 1 drop where?");
                player = 254;//char of players piece
            }
            else{
                printf("player 2 drop where?");
                player = 15;//char of player piece
            }
        }
        while(true){//will run untill 'break;'
            if(charsPlaced == 42) break;//if draw
//          cin>>hold;//get user input
            scanf("%d",&hold);
            hold--;//take off 1 to account for arrays starting at 0 not 1
            if(hold <=6 && hold>= 0) break;//if within valid range stop loop
            else printf( "\nplease enter a value between 1 and 7 :");//ask for input and loop again


        }

        if(charsPlaced == 42) break;//if draw 6X7
        hold2 = drop(hold,player);//drop the player store the row in hold2

        if(hold2 == -1) printf("Column is full\nPlease enter anothor number between 1 and 7:");//if error -1 row is full
        else{
            gamewon = check(hold2,hold);//check if game is run
            charsPlaced ++;//another character has been succesfully placed
            system("cls");//This clears the screen works with windows, not nesscery to run game
            display();//displayed updated board
        }
    }
    system("clear");//this clears the screen
    if(charsPlaced == 42){//if draw
        printf("No winner, Game was draw\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
    if(player == 15)//if won by player 2
        printf("gamewon by : player 2\n");
    else printf("gamewon by : player 1\n");//Else won by player 1
    system("pause");//pauses before exit so players can see who won, works with windows
    return 0;//Exit application
}
```

Comment: Windows or Linux OS?

Comment: You have `system("cls");` which you comment "works with windows", you also have `system("clear");` which you comment "this clears the screen". Try both but be consistent.

Comment: Your code is full of meaningless var names, (i,j,ii etc) and for loops with almost-incomprehensible 'clever code' inside. This is of very little use whatsoever to anyone trying to fix problems.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `system("clear")` which is native to Linux OS.
But also using `system("cls")` which is native to Windows OS. Make up your mind, since this is causing your error.

You can actually [detect which OS you are running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor) with some predefined macros.

Comment: I have el capitan os so the same that linux os and i test the two solutions  but i still have the same error of segmentation and for the display of row in my game any suggestions ?:)

Comment: Remove the `system("cls")` and any other Windows commands (`system("pause")`) and it will fix your error, like I stated

Comment: I did it and its works !Thanks its my first post and very thankful of this community ,Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Nevada please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) this answer if it helped you, by clicking the green check mark next to it.