# Confusion around undefined behaviour when compiling for multi-platform

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've recently discovered that it's undefined behaviour to start anything with two underscores in C++.

So I've been fixing all my include guards.

But I've encountered code like

```
#ifdef __WINDOWS___
#endif
#ifdef __GNUC__
#endif
```

But isn't using `__GNUC__` on a windows compiler UB and vice-versa? What should I do here?

Comment: Double underscores are reserved for the implementation to define. These macros are defined (or not defined) by the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the rules slightly.

It's fine for you to *use* something that has (or hasn't) been `#DEFINE`d by your toolchain, *even* if it starts with two underscores.

It's certainly **not** fine for your to `#DEFINE` something starting with two underscores yourself.

This is a useful convention; it means that your source code cannot clash with the way your compiler implements the C++ standard.

And I'm glad you're fixing your include guards!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it would look better if you write:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
...
#endif
```

because _WIN32 is defined for all Windows C++/C compilers.
Next Windows doesn't support GCC per se. It does have a minimalistic port called MinGW. And because of that you should write:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
...
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't think I should mess about with the header too much!

Comment: I don't think it's very lot... And, there is some platform-specific macros data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor

Comment: Thanks for this, I've voted up but had to accept only one answer.