# g++ compiler macro in c11

Tags: linux, g++

in my centos7.0 system,
when i compile the code with g++ test.cpp -o test,
the output is "is linux system"

when compile with g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test
the output is "is not linux system"

why in c11 the compiler default macro changed?

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    #ifdef linux
        cout<<"is linux system\n";
    #else
        cout<<"is not linux system\n";
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`linux` is not a reserved identifier according to ISO C or C++ standards (all versions), so it is not allowed to be predefined.  Hence the behaviour under `-std=c++11`.

The behaviour with no `std` switch is a GNU variant which does not conform to ISO standards, in which `linux` is defined (along with various other things).

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor) for some ideas about detecting the system while complying with ISO standards. Perhaps `__linux__` will be suitable.  Another option would be to use `-std=gnu++11`, which is a different GNU variant that includes some C++11 features.