# How to combine ifndef win32 with ifndef iOS

Tags: c++, ios, ifndef

I have a C++ code section that I want to exclude it from building iOS.

How should I do it?

**Follow up question:**
If I already have an `#ifndef WIN32`. I want to combine exclusion of `WIN32` with `iOS` is it possible to do something like `#ifndef WIN32 & iOS`?
How should I exclude my code from building on `Win32` & `iOS` both in one clause?

**PS:**
I see a lot of posts explaining how to `#ifndef` out iOS but how do I combing it with `#ifndef WIN32` is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To exclude your code from being built on both WIN32 and iOS you need to use `#if/#endif` instead of `#ifndef/#endif`. If you have not defined a macro to detect compilation for iOS already, then take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920028/8378600). Otherwise, preventing it can be done similarly to this:

```
#if !defined(WIN32) && !defined(YOUR_IOS_MACRO_HERE)
// Your code here
#endif // !defined(WIN32) && !defined(YOUR_IOS_MACRO_HERE)
```

The reason you use `#if` instead of `#ifndef` is because the former allows multiple statements to be linked with `&&` or `||`, whereas the latter only checks the existence of a single macro.