# Preprocessor #if in Objective C misevaluating?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have code that says (literally):

```
#define BUILD_PLATFORM ios
#if BUILD_PLATFORM==macos
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#elif BUILD_PLATFORM==ios
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

However when I attempt to build the project, it still tries to import AppKit/AppKit.h, giving an error that the header cannot be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920028/754705

Comment: @Michael this is less about platform detection and more about referencing variables defined in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with C-preprocessor is that it can compare only numbers. Both `ios` and `macos` are literals that cannot really be compared. You would have to define them first, e.g.

```
#define ios 1
#define macos 2
```

However, if you do that, please, use better names that won't conflict with your code.

If you want to know how Apple does it, see file "Availability.h" which is accessible for both iOS and Mac OS and probably it's the thing you should be using, e.g:

```
#ifdef __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#else
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

When using CMake, the following works:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions(-DPLATFORM=${PLATFORM})  # Set to the target platform
```

Objective C:

```
#if defined(PLATFORM_macos)
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#elif defined(PLATFORM_ios)
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```