# Makefile, modify command based on the OS

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, conditional-compilation

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919996/how-to-detect-reliably-mac-os-x-ios-linux-windows-in-c-preprocessor) question, I wrote a Makefile that starts with

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++17  -Wall -O3 -g

ifeq ( $( shell uname ), "Linux" )
CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
endif


LIBS= -pthread
INCLUDES = -I.
TARGETS= my targets...
```

I need to pass the `-fopenmp` flag only if I'm compiling on linux and not when I'm compiling on Mac.

My problem is that this don't work and the flag never get passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gmake`'s syntax is quite sensitive to whitespace (especially `gmake` macros). Additionally, the output of `uname` does not include quotes.

This should be:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++17  -Wall -O3 -g

ifeq ($(shell uname),Linux)
CXXFLAGS += -fopenmp
endif

zz:
    echo $(CXXFLAGS)
```

Result:

```
$ make zz
echo -std=c++17  -Wall -O3 -g -fopenmp
-std=c++17 -Wall -O3 -g -fopenmp
```

Comment: It works now. Didn't know it was so sensitive to spaces