# How to addin specific package if cake running in windows

Tags: c#, cross-platform, cakebuild

I have cake file that I want to run in Windows and Ubuntu.

In Windows we need Cake.EntityFramework `addin` and in Ubuntu we do not need it.

So I want to write some platform specific `addin` like below

```
#if WINDOWS
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.EntityFramework&version=0.3.0
#endif
```

But I do not know how to do it?

Comment: This should do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5920028/5457940

Comment: No, your link is just work for C++, My problem is for cake and running in C# context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake pre-processing for `#addin`, `#tool`, `#load`, `#module`, etc. does not support conditionals (`#if`). I'd suggest splitting your Cake files to multiple, one `windows.cake`, one `linux.cake` and one `shared.cake`. You can load shared logic using the `#load` directive.

Comment: Is it possible to add this feature in Cake, or it is not possible with current design of Cake?

Comment: Not feasible to implement at this point. Also, last time I checked this wasn't either supported in vanilla C# scripting (csx).

Comment: See https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/1860 for more info.